# Couldn't not fetching the data from Spotify API with Combine framework in SwiftUI

Tags: api, swiftui, spotify, combine

Here is my thought, I want to present the data when the user searching via `$artistName` then combine framework could help me to request the data from the server.

I don't know which step I'm wrong. When I try to fetch the data via the simulator. It will show the unknown error and the rest of these.

```
2020-10-23 03:56:38.220523+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667554] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
Fetch failed: Unknown error
2020-10-23 03:56:40.114906+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115071+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115255+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115360+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115516+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115613+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115723+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_connected_path [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_path on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.115924+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] Connection 2: unable to determine interface type without an established connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.116069+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] Connection 2: unable to determine interface classification without an established connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.116381+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.120441+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] [connection] nw_connection_copy_metadata [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_metadata on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.120579+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] Connection 2: unable to determine interface type without an established connection
2020-10-23 03:56:40.121823+0800 PodcastSearchV2[42967:667546] Connection 2: unable to determine interface type without an established connection
```

This is my response.

```
struct DataResponseSpotify: Codable {
    var episodes: PodcastItemSpotify
}

struct PodcastItemSpotify: Codable {
    var items: [PodcastItemsDetailsSpotify]
}

struct PodcastItemsDetailsSpotify: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let description: String
    let images: [Images]
    let name: String
    let external: String
    
    var externalURL: URL? {
        return URL(string: external)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case description
        case images
        case name
        case external = "external_urls"
    }
}

struct Images: Codable {
    let url: String
    
    var imageURL: URL? {
        return URL(string: url)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url
    }
}

struct Token: Codable {
    let accessToken: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accessToken = "access_token"
    }
}
```

This is how I write in the model.

```
class DataObserverSpotify: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var artistName = ""
    @Published var token = ""
    @Published var fetchResult = [PodcastItemsDetailsSpotify]()
    var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    let podsURLComponents = PodsFetcher()
    
    init() {
        getToken()
        $artistName
            .debounce(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .compactMap { query in
                let url = self.podsURLComponents.makeURLComponentsForSpotify(withName: query, tokenAccess: self.token)
                return URL(string: url.string ?? "")
            }
            .flatMap(fetchDatatesting)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.fetchResult, on: self)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
     
    func fetchDatatesting(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<[PodcastItemsDetailsSpotify], Never> {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: DataResponseSpotify.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .map(\.episodes.items)
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    
    func getToken() {
        let parameters = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[example-refresh-token]"
        let postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("Basic exampleBasicAuth=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("inapptestgroup=; __Host-device_id=example_id; __Secure-example=; csrf_token=example", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                if let token = try? decoder.decode(Token.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.token = token.accessToken
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `getToken` that sets the token **asynchronously**, yet without waiting you immediately  attempt to create a URL assuming that the token is available inside `.compactMap` - and it's not yet available by that time.

So, you have to "wait" for it, which, with Combine, you could do in multiple ways.

The simplest (cheapest) change with what you currently have is to combine the `$token` with the `$artistName` publishers:

```
$artistName
    .debounce(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .removeDuplicates()
    .combineLatest($token.filter { !$0.isEmpty }) // waits for a non-empty token
    .compactMap { (query, token) in
       var url = ... // construct URL from query and token
       return url
    }
    .flatMap(fetchDatatesting)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    // I used sink, since assign causes a self retain cycle
    .sink { [weak self] result in self?.fetchResult = result }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

---

But you really should redesign your `getToken` method - it's not written well because it's an async function, yet it doesn't have a completion handler.

For example, like this:

```
func getToken(_ completion: @escaping (Token) -> Void) {
   // set-up, etc..   
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      // error handling, etc...
      if let token = try? decoder.decode(Token.self, from: data) {
          completion(token)
      }

   }.resume()
}
```

```
// usage
getToken { 
   self.token = $0
}
```

Or, since you're using Combine, you can re-write it to return a publisher (I'm ignoring errors here to keep it concise):

```
func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<Token?, Never> {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you help me a lot. I'm gonna take some research.